# DateTime Conversion Fails/Succeeds on different computers

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, typeconverter

I'm attempting to convert a string to a DateTime, and on one computer, it works fine, but on another, it doesn't! The computer it works on is running 32 bit windows 7, the computer it doesn't work on is running 64 bit windows 7. Heres the cod:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < (lines / 5); i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4]);
                TransactionList.Add(new Transaction
                {
                    TotalEarned = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5)]),
                    TotalCost = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 1]),
                    TotalHST = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 2]),
                    Category = stringArray[(i * 5) + 3],
                    HoursSince2013 = Convert.ToDateTime(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4])
                });
            }
```

The `MessageBox` is there just to check what string is failing to convert, and it's this, in the first iteration: `10/26/2013 11:58:03 AM`

Any clue why this is failing to convert on one of my computers?? I'm completely confused...

Thanks!
Nathan

Comment: How does it fail? What cultures are the computers?

Comment: Wow, just discovered another bizarre fact. It actually works on one of the accounts on the computer, but not the other. Both accounts are administrators.

Comment: @Nathan It's likely that one account has the culture setup differently

Comment: I'll try your solutions and let you know what happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any clue why this is failing to convert on one of my computers??

The most common cause is a difference in culture.  Since you're not specifying a specific culture, the current culture on the system is used.

Try using:

```
HoursSince2013 = Convert.ToDateTime(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: `CultureInfo` doesn't exist in context. Is a namespace required?

Comment: @nathan `System.Globalization`

Comment: Not sure if namespace is the right name, I mean the `using system.x` stuff. :p

Answer (score 0):

If you can change Windows settings then it could be much easier. Just had a similar issue and one machine runs in UK so 19/4/2000 (19th April 2000) is a correct date, but then the other one is located in US and 19/4/2000 is incorrect as there is only 12 months in calendar year (4th UNKNOWN 2000).